# mpdf import all pages from another pdf document

Tags: pdf, import, mpdf

I want to be able to append an entire pdf document in the document I am creating with mpdf.

I can import one page using the following code:

```
$mpdf->SetImportUse(); 

$pagecount = $mpdf->SetSourceFile('testfile.pdf');

$tplId = $mpdf->ImportPage($pagecount, 50, 50, 100, 100);

$mpdf->UseTemplate($tplId, '', '', 100, 100);

$mpdf->Output();
```

but is there a way to import all pages rather than just the last page?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use page count you get form setting source file in a loop (like below)

```
$pdf = new mPDF();
$pdf->SetImportUse();
$pagecount = $pdf->SetSourceFile($dashboard_pdf_file);
    for ($i=1; $i<=$pagecount; $i++) {
        $import_page = $pdf->ImportPage();
        $pdf->UseTemplate($import_page);

        if ($i < $pagecount)
            $pdf->AddPage();
    }
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Now I just need to be able to find the orientation of the imported PDF... Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: mrLami: what if imported pdfs have Table of contents?

Comment: @JamieHall This answer seems to attempt dealing with orientation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49839717/2943403

Answer (score 35):

In the example the index in "$pdf->ImportPage($i)" is missing.

```
$pdf->SetImportUse();
$pagecount = $pdf->SetSourceFile([LOCAL_FILEPATH]);
for ($i=1; $i<=($pagecount); $i++) {
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $import_page = $pdf->ImportPage($i);
    $pdf->UseTemplate($import_page);
}
```