# mpdf join various pdf's

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, mpdf

I have several PDF's to generate, each with its url. For example:

```
Localhost/generatepdf/1
Localhost/generatepdf_color/1
Localhost/generatepdf_color/2
```

I'm doing it in laravel, and every route has its respective function in the controller, so far so good. But what I want to do now, is to put everything together in one link, for example `localhost/allpdfs` where I will have all the pdf's that are generated by the link's above, one after the other, in the same PDF document. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mpdf import all pages from another pdf document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992952/mpdf-import-all-pages-from-another-pdf-document)

Comment: @Christophvh, In this case, mpdf imports pages from a file that already exists and not from a file that is also generated