# How to write text in source pdf file in mpdf library?

Tags: pdf, mpdf

I tried found solution in https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/writetext.html but I am not able to found proper solution.

Actually source pdf to add/write one line in first pdf page but it always return 1 pdf page in output, Rest of pages are gone. Really strange issue. Actually my PDF have multiple page.

Here is my code.

```php
require_once APPPATH . './libraries/mpdf/vendor/autoload.php';
if (ob_get_contents()) ob_end_clean();
$Text = "This score is for Mr. John Deo";
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->SetImportUse(); // only with mPDF <8.0
$file = Sample.pdf'; //This PDF have 2 pages
$pagecount = $mpdf->SetSourceFile($file);
$tplId = $mpdf->ImportPage($pagecount);
$mpdf->UseTemplate($tplId);
$mpdf->SetFont('Arial','B', 11);
$mpdf->WriteText(10,10, $Text );
$mpdf->Output('new.pdf', 'F'); //Return 1 page in output with writetext.
```

Can you please let me know what is wrong with this code? This code is only return first page not all pages in output.

Answer (score 0):

The `ImportPage` function import **only one page** ([see the doc here](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/importpage.html)).

You could use a loop to import each page of your source document.

*(edited to add sample code)*

### Sample code :

- Meant to be added before the call to `Output()` method.
- You have to replace `$tplId = $mpdf->ImportPage($pagecount);` by `$tplId = $mpdf->ImportPage(1);` to write on the first page as `SetSourceFile()` method return the total number of page in the source document.
- the loop start at the second page, because your code already import and write to first page (see prior point).

```php
for ($i = 2; $i <= $pagecount; $i++)
{
    $mpdf->AddPage(); // Add page to output document
    $tplId = $mpdf->ImportPage($i); // Import page as a template
    $mpdf->UseTemplate($tplId); // insert the template in the added page
}
```

(The sample is [inspired by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18361971/15233710).)

**Please note that it's just a sample code**, you should check if the source file exists, check the total number of pages before running the loop, etc.

Comment: Are you able to give me sample code for it because I tried but I am failed to apply.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @VipulJethva I edited my answer to add sample code. Is it more clear ?